# can I add a hostname that is reachable everywhere?

Tags: networking, dns, firewall

i'd like to assign a hostname to our database server that is reachable from both outside and inside the building.

Let's say we own a domain at godaddy: ddd.com

i'd like our staff to reach the database at: data.ddd.com

trouble is, our internal domain differs:

local domain: ggg.local
database server: data1.ggg.local , local IP: 10.0.0.10

We've got a static IP at our building: 108.123.123.123

so, at godaddy, I setup data.ddd.com to point to 108.123.123.123

I also did my firewall-fu to get requests forwarded to the database server.

NOw, how do i get my local users (with lots of laptops) to connect to the same server by using data.ddd.com, instead of data1.ggg.local?

I have full access to our firewall, local, and public DNS to make this happen.

Also clue me in on any/everything i'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be an issue, once you set up your router/firewall to port forward the database to your internal database server. What'll happen when local machine try to connect to data.ddd.com, is that it'll in effect try to connect to its own gateway, which should then forward the requests back to the database server.

One caveat is that it is easy to forget that requests would then becoming from the local network, instead of outside, something some routers will need a specific port forwarding rule for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is a local DNS service. It is quite likely that you router (which I suspect is currently dealing out the ggg.local stuff) may not be able to do this so you would need something to run a DNS on.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions. The first is that you put the data.ddd.com A record in your local DNS server configuration. This is assuming you have a DNS server that you can configure. Unfortunately this is not the case for most soho routers. The second options is to add data.ddd.com to your local hosts file.

In both solutions you point data.ddd.com to the local IP address. This has the benefit of not putting unnecessary load on your router and your router doesn't have to support port reflection for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have access to your **local** DNS, so just add a record for  data.ddd.com pointing to 10.0.0.10 in your local DNS.